# Display multiple social buttons only after they are all loaded from each source?

Tags: jquery

What type of jQuery function could I use to wait to display multiple social buttons (i.e. Facebook Like/Send, Twitter Follow/Tweet, Google+) only after they have all been loaded from their respective source. The problem I am enounctering is after a page is loaded I have these social buttons on, I have to wait one-by-one as these buttons download and it doesn't look attractive to the user. Any ideas for what I can do about this?

Comment: you can store the data / images (if any exist) locally?

Comment: @rlemon -- in other words cache the buttons?

Comment: I think he means host the images locally on the same server.  However, you'll have the same problem no matter where they're hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them all in a single container `<div>` with its style set to `visibility:hidden;`.

Then after `window.load()` fires, which waits for all images on the page to load, use jQuery to make it display again...

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myContainerDiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

As opposed to `display:none;`, using `visibility:hidden;` will ensure that the hidden object still takes up the same amount of space in the content flow.  Changing it to `visibility:visible;` simply toggles it without altering the position of the surrounding content.

Comment: this works well. Do you suggest I cache buttons as they appear on pretty much every page of my site?

Comment: @Brian:  The user's browser should automatically handle any necessary image caching.  If another page on the same domain uses the same images at the same URL's, they'll be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Use a service such as [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) to do this for you.

Comment: There might be some concern with tracking cookies and such.

Comment: @Diodeus - also AddThis while good in some respects, doesn't provide full functionality like the Facebook "Send" button.